# Pivoting a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
            ID  Datetime              Y
0         1000  00:29:59          0.117
1         1000  00:59:59          0.050
2         1000  01:29:59          0.025
3         1000  01:59:59          0.025
4         1000  02:29:59          0.049
        ...       ...            ...
48973133  2999  21:59:59          0.618
48973134  2999  22:29:59          0.495
48973135  2999  22:59:59          0.745
48973136  2999  23:29:59          0.514
48973137  2999  23:59:59          0.419
```

The `Datetime` column is not actually in that format, here it is:

```
0           00:29:59
1           00:59:59
2           01:29:59
3           01:59:59
4           02:29:59
              ...   
48973133    21:59:59
48973134    22:29:59
48973135    22:59:59
48973136    23:29:59
48973137    23:59:59
Name: Datetime, Length: 48973138, dtype: object
```

I am trying to run the following pivot code:

```
print(df.assign(group=df.index//48).pivot(index='group', values='Y', columns=df['Datetime'][0:48]))
```

But i am getting following error:

```
KeyError: '00:29:59'
```

How can i fix it? I expect to get 48 columns (1 day of half-hourly measured data) in the pivoted dataframe, so my columns should be:

```
00:29:59 00:59:59 01:29:59 ... 23:29:59 23:59:59
```

The first row should have the first 48 values of `Y`, the second row should have the next `48`, and so on.

EDIT: Picture of the `cumcount()`issue:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? have you tried `df.pivot(index='ID', values='Y', columns='Datetime')`?

Comment: @Tranbi Yes, i had already tried that, and i got the following error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. That's why i tried with `df.assing()`. The expected output is like i said before. The columns should be values from `Datetime` column, and in the first row of the pivoted tablet, i should get the first 48 values from original dataframe (`df['Y'][0:48]`). The second row should have the next 48 values (`df['Y'][48:96]`), the third row should have the next 48 values (`df['Y'][96:144]`), and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems you have the same `ID` for multiple days. I would therefore suggest to keep track of the day with `cumcount` before pivoting:

```
df['Day'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Datetime']).cumcount()
df.pivot(index=['ID', 'Day'], values='Y', columns='Datetime')
```

Edit: based on your comment under my answer, it seems that not all days have all timestamps. A solution could be to generate the right number of timestamps (repeating `[00:29:59 00:59:59 01:29:59 ... 23:29:59 23:59:59]`) and add missing values to df. This would be quite CPU intensive though:

```
import math
from itertools import cycle
# gapless list of Datetime:
dt = (x for i in range(24) for x in [f"{i}:29:59".zfill(8), f"{i}:59:59".zfill(8)])
for i, t in enumerate(cycle(dt)):
    if i == len(df):
        break
    if df.loc[i, 'Datetime'] != t:
        if t == "00:29:59":     # filling missing IDs
            id_ = df.loc[i, 'ID']
        else:
            id_ = df.loc[i-1, 'ID']
        df = pd.concat([df.loc[0:i-1], pd.DataFrame({'ID': id_, 'Datetime': [t]}), df.loc[i:]], ignore_index=True)
```

Then apply `groupby` and `pivot` like shown above.

Edit2: using `cycle` instead of `chain` + `tee`

Comment: The `cumcount()` is not tracking the day correctly. For example, for `ID = 1999`, when `Day=510` ends at `23:59:59`, the next row that should be `Day=511` at `00:29:59` is instead `Day=513` at `00:29:59`. I could edit the post with a picture of this if you wish so.  Because of this problem with `cumcount()` the pivoted df has some `NaN` values.

Comment: Some timestamps are likely missing on some days. See my updated answer to fill them.

Comment: Btw if timestamps are missing, you can't avoid having NaN values in the end result.

Comment: Actually every day has all timestamps. What happens is that some ID does not have all days, but i was expecting that this would not matter. For example, i have checked that `ID = 1960` only have 94 days of data, while `ID = 1961` have 536 days (wich is in fact the maximum day of data that has been recorded). And since the number of days does not really matter to me, i was not expecting to get any NaNs.

Comment: "every day has all timestamps". If this was the case, shouldn't the number of rows be a multiple of 48? What you're pointing out about number of days per ID shouldn't play any role with the code I provided.

Comment: You are totally right. I just checked again and actually i have a multiple of 24 timestamps that are missing. I will use the solution you provided to fill those timestamps, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for avoid `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` - if same value per `ID` and `Datetime` valuesa are aggregate - here is used default function `mean`:

```
td = pd.timedelta_range('00:00:00','24:00:00', freq='30Min')[1:]

td = [f'{x - pd.Timedelta("1 sec")}'[-8:] for x in td]
print (td)
['00:29:59', '00:59:59', '01:29:59', '01:59:59', '02:29:59', '02:59:59', '03:29:59', '03:59:59', '04:29:59', '04:59:59', '05:29:59', '05:59:59', '06:29:59', '06:59:59', '07:29:59', '07:59:59', '08:29:59', '08:59:59', '09:29:59', '09:59:59', '10:29:59', '10:59:59', '11:29:59', '11:59:59', '12:29:59', '12:59:59', '13:29:59', '13:59:59', '14:29:59', '14:59:59', '15:29:59', '15:59:59', '16:29:59', '16:59:59', '17:29:59', '17:59:59', '18:29:59', '18:59:59', '19:29:59', '19:59:59', '20:29:59', '20:59:59', '21:29:59', '21:59:59', '22:29:59', '22:59:59', '23:29:59', '23:59:59']
```

---

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Datetime', values='Y', aggfunc='mean')
print (df1)
Datetime  00:29:59  00:59:59  01:29:59  01:59:59  02:29:59  21:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000         0.117      0.05     0.025     0.025     0.049       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN     0.618   

Datetime  22:29:59  22:59:59  23:59:59  
ID                                      
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN  
2999         0.495     0.745    0.4665
```

If need all times add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Datetime', values='Y', aggfunc='mean')
         .reindex(td, axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df1)
Datetime  00:29:59  00:59:59  01:29:59  01:59:59  02:29:59  02:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000         0.117      0.05     0.025     0.025     0.049       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  03:29:59  03:59:59  04:29:59  04:59:59  05:29:59  05:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  06:29:59  06:59:59  07:29:59  07:59:59  08:29:59  08:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  09:29:59  09:59:59  10:29:59  10:59:59  11:29:59  11:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  12:29:59  12:59:59  13:29:59  13:59:59  14:29:59  14:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  15:29:59  15:59:59  16:29:59  16:59:59  17:29:59  17:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  18:29:59  18:59:59  19:29:59  19:59:59  20:29:59  20:59:59  \
ID                                                                     
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   
2999           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   

Datetime  21:29:59  21:59:59  22:29:59  22:59:59  23:29:59  23:59:59  
ID                                                                    
1000           NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
2999           NaN     0.618     0.495     0.745       NaN    0.4665
```